# Why won't the arms move with my bones?

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I am learning rigging in blender so I made this:

[image]

The bones work fine with everything except for the upper arm on both arms. Take a look here: [image]

Here is my rig:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots Here you go :D [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=LykKoePS" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/LykKoePS/)

Comment: so it looks like you've parented With Empty Groups, you need to select a part of your mesh, for example the chest, then go in the Properties panel > Object Data, Vertex Groups, find the group with the name of the bone that is supposed to control this part (here, Chest) and click Assign

Comment: @moonboots thank you so much, i will try that and let you know what happens! Can you post theat as an answer?

Comment: ok, done, I've added some precisions     ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like you've parented *With Empty Groups*, which makes sense for an object like a robot, which is mechanical and not organic.

For a human, *With Automatic Weight* would be preferable, it would automatically create as many vertex groups as you have bones, and assign these groups to the vertices that these bones are supposed to control. But you'll have smooth transitions between vertices groups, as it is what is supposed to happen in an body.

Smooth transitions between vertex groups is not what you want for a machine, because a piece of a machine is supposed to be only controlled by its own bone. In that case, parent *With Empty Groups*, it creates as many vertex groups as you have bones but for the moment it doesn't assign them to any vertex, you'll be the one that will assign each group to the vertices you want, without any transition.

To do so, once parented *With Empty Groups*, you need to select a part of your mesh, for example the chest, then go in the *Properties* panel > *Object Data, Vertex Groups*, find the group with the name of the bone that is supposed to control this part (here, *Chest*), click *Assign*, and so on fo the other vertices.

Little trick: To sort the vertex groups by alphabetic order, click on the down arrow button on the right of the vertex groups list and choose *Sort By Name*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to do this, I am still having trouble, is it possible to have a quick video to show the steps because I think maybe I just misunderstood... Sorry for bothering you :D

Comment: what step don't you understand?

Comment: Well first of all I never made any bones called foot.l, foot.r etc... So where did they come from?? Sorry if these are simple questions im really new to 3d modeling :D

Comment: I can't tell, if they haven't been created by the parenage it means these groups were already existing in the mesh, someone hase created them, but you don't need to worry about that as long as it doesn't cause problem (you can also delete them if they are not useful)

Comment: Im also not sure what to do with empty groups, I got a bit confused there

Comment: With Empty Groups is the method you've used to parent the mesh to the armature it creates in your mesh as many groups as you have bones, bones are going to control the groups that have the same name as them, except this method has not yet assigned any vertex to these groups for the moment, you are the one that will do the work, it's the best parentage method for meshes like machines or robots, With Automatic Weight would create vertex groups AND assign the vertices to these groups, but the assignation would be smooth, that's not what you want for a robot.

Comment: Thanks, how do I check what I assigned a part of the mesh too?

Comment: you mean what group to assign to what part of the mesh? You need to check the bones name, for example the upper left arm is called UpperArm.001 (which is not a good name btw, it will cause problem when you'll want to inverse poses, rename it UpperArm.L, it will automatically change the vertex group name), then select the part of the mesh this bone is supposed to control, go in the Vertex Groups list, find the group called UpperArm.001, click Assign.

Comment: Yes, but how do i check what bone i assigned the mesh to check if i made an mistake

Comment: to check bone after bone, select the armature, shift select the object, switch to Weight Paint, select a bone and see what influence it has, then select another bone, etc... Is it your question? If your mesh is in Weight Paint mode you can also select the vertex groups one by one in the Vertex Groups list

Comment: Ok, also what did you mean when you said "which is not a good name btw, it will cause problem when you'll want to inverse poses, rename it UpperArm.L, it will automatically change the vertex group name" what did you mean inverse poses?

Comment: when you create a walk cycle for example, you'll need to flip the poses: first move the left leg forwards and keyframe, then, instead of creating the right leg going forwards, select the left leg on its forwards position, Ctrl C to copy and simply Shift Ctrl V, the right leg will automatically go forwards, don't forget to create the keyframe with "i" (insert keyframe) though

Comment: So I am probably going to make the animations in unity game engine, so would the name still be a problem also i can just rename the bones in unity)

Comment: I can't tell for Unity  ;)

Comment: Ok haha, also I want it so that when i shoot the robot its body parts can fall off, would i have to make each body part seperate?

Comment: it depends how you want the body to fall off, does every part stay intact or does it explode, etc? I can't tell a lot about explosion as I'm not familiar with it, maybe ask a new question with details

Comment: Its not really about explosion its just when it gets shot, just have the arm detach, would i need to make each part of body (like chest, arm etc.) separate! Btw really appreciate you helping me out here :D

Comment: yes so you need to keep them separate, you can either give them physics (rigid body) or fake physics (and animate), but you'll need to disable the armature in the modifier stack (i.e. keyframe the eye icon). I haven't try this so I may forget something

Comment: Why would I need to disable armiture?

Comment: oh actually your robot is made of one object, to make it fall in different piece it would be much convenient to separate it in different objects, in that case the parenting can be simpler, select the object, select the bone, then ctrl P and choose parent to > Bone

Comment: I don't know if this is good or bad but what I did was i selected the arm, right clicked then said separate selection, what do you thiunk?

Comment: yes if you want your robot to collapse you need to separate each piece, and you'll have to parent with a different method: select the object, then shift select the armature, switch it to Pose mode, select the good bone and press ctrl P > Bone. You'll then need to give a Physic > Rigid Body to each of your pieces, and the option that you'll keyframe will be the Animated option, so that you can decide wether the piece is controlled by the bone or by the physics

Comment: I can add the rigidbodys in unity so should i just Select the object then right click separate then re-assign the bone? Also even when I do right click then separate selection it still moves properly in pose mode

Comment: yes because some vertices have already been assigned to vertex groups. Can't tell about Unity, I don't know Unity  ;)

Comment: I am not gonna lie I have hardly any idea what you mean by vertex groups and vertices haha

Comment: maybe follow some basic tutorial on Blender rigging  ;)

Comment: Ok, I have one last thing though, so I was testing and this happened when I imported it to my game (i updated the question)

Comment: you need to flip the normals, select the chest, go in edit mode, select all and press shift N

Comment: Thank you so much moonboots! Really helped me out been trying to figure this out for a long time finally got it to work :) Have a great day!

Comment: you're welcome, good luck

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109750/discussion-on-answer-by-moonboots-why-wont-the-arms-move-with-my-bones).